# Conditions on the heat source so that a steady state solutions exists.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, steady-state

Consider the heat equation,
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \left(K_0(x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)+Q(t)$$ 
$$u(t,x=1)=0$$
$$u(t,x=2)=1$$

where $K_{0}=x^2$

Now the question is under what conditions on the heat source $Q(t)$ does a steady state solution exist?

So far what I have done is expanded out to get this equation,
$$-Q(t)=2x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + x^2 \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x ^2}$$
Which according to wolfram alpha has solution,
$$u(x,t) = -Q(t)ln(x)+\frac{c_1}{x}+c_2$$
from this it looks like there is always a steady state solution right?

Comment: If you want it to be steady, $Q(t)$ will have to be constant in $t$.  Or did you mean $Q(x)$?

Comment: It is suppose to be $Q(t)$. Using the initial conditions I have been able to find that $Q(t)=\frac{c_2}{ln(4)}$ is that how we know it must be constant since $c_2$ is constant?

Comment: The ODE must have two linearly independent solutions, not only the one given by Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: If it's steady state, the only term in the initial equation that could depend on $t$ is $Q(t)$, so that must be constant.

Comment: And then you should get $c_1 = -2-Q \ln(2)$ and $c_2 = 2 + 2 Q \ln(2)$ by plugging Wolfram Alpha's solution in to the boundary conditions.

Comment: @amsmath Wolfram Alpha is giving the general solution of the ODE.  Note the $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, I was retarded. ;-)

Comment: Ah yes the values you got for $c_1$ and $c_2$ are correct I made a mistake in my work. Thanks for all your help I think I understand now.